# Why do you keep the parenthesis in this equation? What is the rule exactly?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In this equation:

$4a – 3(17 – a)$

Why does it reduce to

$4a – (51 – 3a)$

and not

$4a – 51 – 3a$

Do you always keep the parenthesis when you distribute across a parenthesis statement?

Comment: @BenLongo That expression at the end should be $4a - 51 + 3a$. Also you should make this (after correction) an answer.

Comment: The $(17−a)$ is being multiplied by 3 and -1. So if we distribute only the the 3 we get $4a−(51−3a)$. We have to keep the parenthesis because that term is still being multiplied by -1. If we distribute the -1 and the 3 we get $4a−51+3a$, not $4a−51−3a$.

Comment: Recall that subtracting a  positive is equivalent to adding a negative, so rewriting the expression with this in mind may be helpful $$4a-3(17-a) = 4a+(-3)(14-a)$$

Answer (score 2):

A little more explicitly
$$4a–3(17–a) = 4a+[-1\cdot3\cdot(17-a)],$$
meaning that there is a $(-1)$ there but we don't write it. It is implied by the minus sign.
That is why you could distribute the $3$ first and get
$$4a–3(17–a) = 4a-(51-3a)$$
or you could distribute the $(-1)$ first to get
$$4a–3(17–a) = 4a+3(-17+a).$$
This is because multiplication is commutative.

As for a rule, you keep parentheses to enforce the correct order in which to compute an expression. Parentheses take highest priority.
This is [order of operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations).

Comment: where do the square brackets come from in step 1? That's what I'm confused about I think?

Comment: In this case, the square brackets and the round ones are interchangeable. I included the square so I could **preserve** the the order of the expression that was given.

Comment: I could have used round parentheses, but I chose square ones it was easier to read. It was a matter of convenience/aesthetics, nothing more.

Comment: But I guess the takeaway here is that when you multiply and distribute a term through parenthesis... the result is still wrapped in parenthesis? IT doesn't disappear just yet. In the above, the 4a-3(17-a) turns into 4a-(51-3a)? Like, the parenthesis remain after multiplication?

Answer (score 0):

$$4a-3(17-a)$$ is equivalent to $$4a-1*3(17-a)=4a-1[3(17-a)]$$ which is turn equivalent to $$4a-1(51-3a)$$ which in turn gives $$4a-51+3a$$ and **not** $$4a-51-3a$$ as negative times another negative is positive.

To see why negative times negative is positive see this-[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171221170745/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.negxneg.html)

Note-We always can write any number $n=n*1$ or $-n=-n*1=n*-1.$

Also,order of operations in an equation is $BODMAS$-
Bracket,Of,Division,Multiplication,Addition,Subtraction.

Comment: where do the square brackets come from in step 2?

Comment: @Jwan622-It'snot come from anywhere...:-)...it is given so as to easily separate out operations for convenience of reading.by the way *square brackets* is not a big deal...it could have been replaced by *round brackets*.But according to recommendations,there is an order of brackets-round,curved and then square....I have not used curved here because of programming difficulty in $LATEX$.

Comment: But I guess the takeaway here is that when you multiply and distribute a term through parenthesis... the result is still wrapped in parenthesis? IT doesn't disappear just yet. In the above, the 4a-3(17-a) turns into 4a-(51-3a)? Like, the parenthesis remain after multiplication?

Comment: As I said before there is a rule and order of operations.After I remove the curved brackets the I start with the work of the round brackets....to show the steps properly I have showed that it remains as the work of the previous brackets is done and now it is time to start work with the next set of brackets....